# Donchian Strategy. Error in eval(parse(text = formula), as.list(data)) and Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = seq(ncol(tmp_val))) :

Tags: r

I am trying to apply this strategy that I have coded in R and I am receiving 2 errors that are rather hard to debug. Can I get some help on how to fix these errors and possibly make my code more efficient? Using this on two ETFs but focusing on 1 for this part to retrieve help. I am just beginning in R as an FYI.

This is coding Donchian's Strategy using 20-day and 10-day channels with a fast and slow EMA filter.

Coded below is with a lot of my notes and other unnecessary areas removed, such as charts and stuff.

The generalistic phrasing of these errors has prompted me to scan for what looks to be missing (i.e. `EMA1`). Although I believe I have created the "object" for this it is apparent I am not. Same with the `colnames` error... I do not have a clue where to begin.

```
library(TTR)
library(IBrokers)
library(xts)
library(blotter)

currency("USD")
stock("VTI",currency="USD",multiplier=1)
stock("BND",currency="USD",multiplier=1)

initDate <-'2007-12-31'
startDate <-'2008-01-01'
endDate <-'2016-12-31'
initEq <- 1e6

Sys.setenv(TZ = "UTC")

getSymbols('VTI', 
           from = startDate,
           to = endDate,
           index.class = "POSIXct",
           adjust = T
           )

#not sure if needed
VTI = to.monthly(VTI, 
               indexAt = 'endof',
               drop.time=FALSE
               )

#HLVTI <- cbind(VTI$VTI.High,VTI$VTI.Low) incase it is needed below

#ACTUAL STRATEGY - initializing name to strategy

D.VTI <- "VTI Don"

#giving name D.VTI to portoflio and account.

initPortf(D.VTI, 'VTI', initDate = initDate) #portfolio startes at inital date
initAcct(D.VTI, portfolios = D.VTI, initDate = initDate, initEq=initEq) 
initOrders(portfolio = D.VTI, initDate = initDate)  

strategy(D.VTI, store = TRUE)

strat <- getStrategy(D.VTI) #retrieve strategy object
class(strat) #check class
summary(strat) #check what is inside the strategu itself. Check periodically.

#####
#Indicators. DCH 20-10, EMA 25-360 or EMA1-12 in months


add.indicator(strategy = D.VTI, 
              name = "DonchianChannel",
              arguments = list(HL = quote(HLC(VTI)[,2:3]),
                               n = 10),
              label = "DCH10")

add.indicator(strategy = D.VTI, 
              name = "DonchianChannel",
              arguments = list(HL = quote(HLC(VTI)[,2:3]),
                               n = 20),
              label = "DCH20")

add.indicator(strategy = D.VTI,
              name = "EMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(VTI)), n=1),
              label = "EMA1")

add.indicator(strategy = D.VTI,
              name = "EMA",
              arguments = list(x = quote(Cl(VTI)), n=12),
              label = "EMA12")

summary(getStrategy(D.VTI))

#Signals

add.signal(D.VTI, name = "sigComparison",
           arguments = list(columns = c("EMA1", "EMA12"), relationship = "gte"),
           label = "EMA1.gte.EMA12")

add.signal(D.VTI, name = "sigComparison",
           arguments = list(columns = c("EMA1", "EMA12"), relationship = "lte"),
           label = "EMA1.lte.EMA12")

add.signal(D.VTI, name = "sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("Close", "high.DCH10"), relationship = "eq"),
           label = "Close.eq.high.DCH10")

add.signal(D.VTI, name = "sigCrossover",
           arguments = list(columns = c("Close", "low.DCH10"), relationship = "eq"),
           label = "Close.eq.low.DCH10")

#Garrett and Brian's suggestion

add.signal(D.VTI, name="sigFormula", 
           arguments = list(columns=c("EMA1","EMA12","high.DCH20", "Close"),
                            formula = "(EMA1 > EMA12) & (CLose > high.DCH20)",
                            label="trigger", 
                            cross=TRUE),
           label="EMAFilterLong"  #Close.gt.high.DCH20"
           )

add.signal(D.VTI, name="sigFormula", 
           arguments = list(columns=c("EMA1","EMA12","high.DCH20", "Close"),
                            formula = "(EMA1 < EMA12) & (CLose < low.DCH20)",
                            label="trigger", 
                            cross=TRUE),
           label="EMAFilterShort"     #Close.lt.low.DCH20
)

summary(getStrategy(D.VTI))

add.rule(D.VTI, name = 'ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol = "EMAFilterLong",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty=100,
                          ordertype='market',
                          orderside='long'),
         type='enter'
         )

add.rule(D.VTI, name = 'ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol = "Close.eq.low.DCH10",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty='all',
                          ordertype='market',
                          orderside='long'),
         type='exit')

add.rule(D.VTI, name = 'ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol = "EMAFilterShort",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty='100',
                          ordertype='market',
                          orderside='short'),
         type='enter')

add.rule(D.VTI, name = 'ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol = "Close.eq.high.DCH10",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty='all',
                          ordertype='market',
                          orderside='short'),
         type='exit')

summary(getStrategy(D.VTI))

applyStrategy(strategy = D.VTI, portfolios = D.VTI)
```

I am not expecting anything more than to run this strategy and to be able to analyze the results. Instead I am retrieving this error and some warnings. The full error once applyStrategy is applied:

```
Error in eval(parse(text = formula), as.list(data)) : 
  object 'EMA1' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In match.names(columns, colnames(data)) :
  all columns not located in EMA1 EMA12 for VTI.Open VTI.High VTI.Low VTI.Close VTI.Volume VTI.Adjusted high.DCH10 mid.DCH10 low.DCH10 high.DCH20 mid.DCH20 low.DCH20 EMA.EMA1 EMA.EMA12 EMA1.gte.EMA12
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = seq(ncol(tmp_val))) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions.
```

Comment: On the face of it, you have labeled elements of objects to be called EMA1 but you have not created an object that is called EMA1. Which package in your library calls uses the function add.signal?

Comment: Yes. It would look like this is correct. The same argument could be made for DCH20 (for the donchian indicators)... that I have them stated inside function calls for add.indicator. Am I off base with this and these need to be made into actual objects in the enviornment? Also, i believe the add.signal is in quantstrat.

Comment: Assuming that from the AapplyStrategy documentation that the D.VTI is a correctly specified strategy, it should be fine. If seems a bit strange that the portfolio is the same as the strategy. That does not make sense. One is a strategy object and the other a list of portfolios.

Comment: Yes. This is how were were taught, more or less. I did end up going back and specifying the objects and ended up with a new error but, as you said and how I was taught, this should have been fine to begin with. Any advice on how to get this to run? Thanks for the edit busybear.